# How to stop blink when hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the blinking to stop when ever the button is hovered. Any ideas for this?

```js
      function blinker() {
        $( & #39;.blinking&# 39;).fadeOut(1000);
        $( & #39;.blinking&# 39;).fadeIn(1000);
      }
      setInterval(blinker, 4000);
```

Comment: Attach an event handler, name your interval and do `clearinterval` on hover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store a handler on your interval, and use it to clear it when your button is hovered:

```
function blinker() {
    $('.blinking').fadeOut(1000);
    $('.blinking').fadeIn(1000);
}
intervalHandler = setInterval(blinker, 4000);

$('.blinking').mouseover(function() {
    clearInterval(intervalHandler);
    intervalHandler = undefined;
});
```

If you wish the blinking to be active again whenever the button is not hovered anymore, you can set the interval back:

```
$('.blinking').mouseout(function() {
    if (!intervalHandler) {
        intervalHandler = setInterval(blinker, 4000);
    }
});
```

By setting the handler to undefined when the interval is cleared, you ensure to never set the interval twice, which would prevent you to clear them both and will make the blinking persistent.

I edited my answer thanks to @Luger's comment.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to setInterval back after mouseover event?

Comment: Hmmm.. This should work but it's totally not working for me. Still blinking

Comment: Have you checked that the over function is fired? Also take care of the scope of your handler variable, in my code I assumed it was global, which might be the case for you.